# How to add firebase SDK for ios in Flutter without X - Code

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, dart

Well, I just migrated from java for application development to Flutter. I was trying to configure firebase with my project and I did the android part fine. But while configuring .plist file for ios, as I went through several tutorials I found out everyone is using X - Code in order to configure iOS part. I am using a windows laptop and there is no way to install X - Code in it. So how do I configure dependencies for ios? Please guide me.

Comment: You can't develop for iOS without XCode

Comment: First you need to have `ios` folder to set up things for iOS, which you won't have when creating a project in windows.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad Screen shot - [link](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pran-d333b.appspot.com/o/Screenshot%20(10).png?alt=media&token=e42407c0-68b8-4924-a2b2-7e009f563747) I think there is an iOS folder in my flutter application.

Comment: Do you have files like `info.plist`, `podfile`?

Comment: Yes there is info.plist file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you have ios folder in your directory you're not going to set it up without XCode, not even talking about building it. You need XCode for that because of how restrictive Apple is with iOS development.

You can create a virtual environment with macOS, that's your best bet without buying a mac.

Comment: For sure we need XCode for configuration. But can you please give me some time till I explore some solutions.

Answer (score 0):

There is a service in macincloud.com where you can buy month hours in a MAC. I've used before and the service is great.